# What stopwatch timer app uses keyboard shortcuts on macOS?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

It’s not clear which of the timers from this other thread support hotkey / Keyboard only shortcut operation.

- [What stopwatch timer app to use on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125498/what-stopwatch-timer-app-to-use-on-macos)

Can anyone recommend a stopwatch timer for Mac which can be started or stopped using hotkey?

Answer (score 11):

A low-tech solution is to open a terminal window, run `time cat`, and then stop by pressing control-c:

```
$ time cat
^C
4.487
$
```

Two ways to show the number of seconds since the last run:

```
f=${TMPDIR}stopwatch;date +%s>>$f;tail -n2 $f|awk '{l=$0;getline;print $0-l}'
now=$(date +%s);echo $((now-prev));prev=$now
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a very simple Timer application which also allows HotKey setup. Plus, it's open sourced :)

App link: http://joaomoreno.github.io/thyme/
Github source: https://github.com/joaomoreno/thyme

Answer (score 5):

While I'd second running a script like explained above by user3936, I've used this before: http://www.apimac.com/mac/timer/

It has a free version and a paid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is teatimer bash script which uses applescript to show an OSX notification and the built-in `afplay` utility for playing a system sound:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PLONK="afplay /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/dt-confirm.caf &"

eval $PLONK && osascript -e "display notification \"Started: `date +'%A, %d-%B-%y, %H:%M:%S'`\" with title \"Tea\""

declare -a keys=(50 10 30 30.0 180);

declare -A ticks=( \
        [50]="50 sec" \
        [10]="1 min" \
        [30]="1 min 30 sec" \
        [30.0]="2 min" \
        [180]="5 min" \
    );

for key in "${keys[@]}"; do 
    echo "Next: ${ticks[$key]}";
    sleep $key && eval $PLONK && osascript -e "display notification \"Elapsed: ${ticks[$key]}\" with title \"Tea\""
done
```

This will show a notifcation + sound after 50 seconds, 1m, 1m 30s, 2m, 5m. If you modify the script make sure the keys are unique.

[image: teatimer notifcation]

> **NOTE**: The script requires bash v4. By default OSX comes with bash v3.

Answer (score 0):

Stopwatch timer using bash.
Works on macOS.

```
#!/bin/bash

formatSeconds()
{
    ((h=${1}/3600))
    ((m=(${1}%3600)/60))
    ((s=${1}%60))
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d" $h $m $s
}

startTime=$(date +%s)

while [ 1 ]
do
    currentTime=$(date +%s)
    timePassed=$[$currentTime-startTime]

    echo -n "$(formatSeconds $timePassed)"

    sleep 0.5
    echo -en "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

We developed a new app on the Mac App Store called **TeraTime**. It's a free stopwatch and timer app, and we feel the design is a modern and simple app for Mac.

The 'space' key can be used to start and stop both the timer and the stopwatch. The 'R' or 'delete' key can be used to reset the stopwatch.

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/teratime/id1348795218?ls=1&mt=12

If you prefer apps that go through Apple’s review and respect the sandbox and App Store delivery, this might be an alternative to the other apps mentioned.

Full Disclosure: I am part of the team that created this app.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the 0.99$ [M Stopwatch app from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/m-stopwatch/id1260946111?ls=1&mt=12). It will allow you to export the logs to a text file too.

Comment: This app is for mac os x the name is similar to that one but this one is for mac os x, the shortcuts to start the timer is cmd+1 and to stop cmd+4. the link is here https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/m-stopwatch/id1260946111?ls=1&mt=12